Can a black body be in thermal equilibrium if it absorbs thermal radiation from a non-Planckian source?
My understanding is that a Black Body is a physical body that:

Absorbs all incident electromagnetic radiation, regardless of frequency or angle of incidence. This means that its absorptivity is $1$ for all wavelengths ($\alpha(\lambda) = 1$). My interpretation of this is that the absorption spectrum of the black body will match that of the source of the incident radiation, since the black body will absorb all radiation it receives from the source.

In thermal equilibrium, it radiates the maximum possible amount of energy for a given temperature, which is given by Planck’s radiation law. This means that its emissivity is $1$ for all wavelengths ($\epsilon(\lambda)=1$). My interpretation of this is that thermal equilibrium for a black body is only possible if the source of incident radiation also follows a Planckian distribution, since a black body in thermal equilibrium can only emit following a Planckian distribution, so if the source is not Planckian the black body emission spectrum will never match the incident radiation spectrum and Kirchoff's Law of thermal radiation ($\alpha(\lambda) = \epsilon (\lambda)$) will never be fulfilled.


Am I correct in these interpretations? In case that I am, would it be possible for an object that has the ability to behave as black body to be in thermal equilibrium with a non-Planckian source by not behaving as a black body so that it can match the source's emission spectrum?

I would recommend you to read this question and answers therein

You are wrong. Kirchoff's Law does not require that the emission spectrum will match the incident radiation spectrum.
The requirement $\alpha(\lambda)=\varepsilon(\lambda)$ only requires that at a given wavelength the absorptivity equals the emissivity, meaning that:
The quotient defined by the power that is absorbed, divided by what a black body would absorb given the same irradiation, is the same as the quotient defined by the power that is emitted, divided by what a black body would emit given the same temperature. So there are a lot of quantities involved in that sentence, but none of those need be equal, only those two fractions! They must both be given by the same function of wavelength (and possibly temperature).

It is useful to realize that there is the concept of thermodynamic equilibrium, and there is the concept of local thermodynamic equilibrium (LTE).
Thermodynamic equilibrium means no macroscopic net flow of energy in or out of any region, and temperature being the same everywhere.
A black body, in general, is not in thermodynamic equilibrium with its surroundings (and it need not be to be a black body). It can be in thermodynamic equilibrium with other body only in a very special situation: when all its surroundings in all directions have the same temperature, and radiates back at the blackbody with the same intensity the blackbody does, at each frequency interval. For example, the blackbody can be enclosed in a cavity in which the same temperature is maintained (energy does not leak out of it, or is resupplied to keep the temperature constant). If there is no such cavity, and the blackbody is interacting just with radiation of some non-Planckian source, the blackbody is not in thermodynamic equilibrium. If these two bodies are enclosed in a well insulating cavity, then the system will move towards thermodynamic equilibrium, even if emission of one of the bodies is not Planckian (so it is not a black body). Reflections of teh established equilibrium radiation will supply the missing intensity that the non-Planckian body is not emitting, compared to a blackbody of same surface and temperature.
Local thermodynamic equilibrium  (LTE) at any point of a system means that a macroscopic element of the system centered at this point need not be in equilibrium with the surrounding elements, and temperature can vary from point to point, but radiation passing through every point is Planckian, with possible position-dependent temperature. This is approximately the case e.g. when an ember radiates and cools down, or when a piece of Sun interior is traversed by radiation in all directions, but net energy is transported radially from center to surface.
A bodies approximating black body are supposed to be in LTE in their inside, because black body is supposed to absorb all incoming radiation in its surface, so the non-Planckian radiation does not reach the interior. But in your example, when non-Planckian source emits radiation some of which is absorbed by the blackbody, the blackbody surface definitely is not in LTE, as radiation there is a combination of Planckian radiation of the blackbody and the non-Planckian radiation of the other body, and so the resulting radiation there is not Planckian.
